# Where is OpenCV CMake option ANDROID set?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to build a modified OpenCV (4.8.0) from sources for Android on a Windows machine.

To configure CMake right I'm looking at the `opencv/CMakeLists.txt` as mentioned in the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html).

As I'm not very experienced in CMake I'm confused about where the variable `ANDROID` comes from. Example line 508:

```
OCV_OPTION(INSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES "Install Android examples"  OFF IF ANDROID )
```

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ANDROID.html

Comment: Maybe a little to much but let me track down: One parameter for my cmake is `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` referencing an `android.toolchain.cmake` file. This sets the system name. So by using this parameter the option `ANDROID` will be set for my make process, right?

Comment: Yes, since `andoid.toolchain.cmake` [sets `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Android`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake#L211) CMake will set the variable `ANDROID` to `1`.